# Is there an "L" type of five wire connector?

Tags: connector

With the controller shown,

notice the connector heads "west" (yellow),

meaning a tight enclosing cabinet needs to be as wide as the red indication.

[image]

However, if the white connector immediately did a 90 degree turn down

(direction downwards in blue)

you can see it would drastically save width of a tight enclosure.

Is there such a thing?  A 90° version of the white connector seen?

(I suppose ... a 180 degree would be even better, a "backwards" connector)

*Note - of course, for a one-off one could just modify the board and I guess solder on five wires which could hang straight down.  However it's not a reliable pipeline when producing many of them, allowing for easy field repairs, etc etc.*

(FWIW I considered just specifying to "bend down" the five pins on all units, but then the "locking tongue" of the white connector would have to not exist ... again it's a flakey solution.)

---

thanks @RemcoVik, trying my best to add more photos!

It has no identifying marks I can see :/

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: de-solder the connector and straigten the solder end of the pins then re-solder it

Comment: For a lot of connectors yes, "90 degree angled" counterparts do exist. However we would first need to know what kind of connector is on the board currently. Can you provide any details on marking on the connector, pitch, dimensions.

Comment: @RemcoVink , thanks, added photos: sadly no identifying marks! nothing in the doco sheet.

Comment: Can's you redesign the enclosure so the stick is rotated 90/180° and account for that in the program?

Comment: @ratchetfreak - you wouldn't believe it, the bloody thing is even longer, much more, in the other dimension!!  Suckers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a right angle version of that particular one. As Jasen says, the pins are crimped onto the wire and inserted into the housing and that's not really possible with right angles.

But if you measure the pitch you can probably find an IDC connector that will fit where the wires go in at right angles - something like this:

[image]

Alternatively, make a small adaptor board that will sit at right angles with a vertical socket at the top and the same connector as the controller at the bottom pointing downwards. Or even a different socket if it makes assembly easier.

Comment: Good one guys.  I think basically the answer is "no" - which is good to know!

Answer (score 2):

The wire connector is a shell that houses crimped pin sockets, these pin sockets are only available in straight so far as I am aware.

The PCB connector is probably available in vertical (most types are) but I can't identify it from that photo, but changing the connector would require removing the existing connector, or soldering the new connector to the pins of the existing connector.